# Bootstrap 3 centering elements in collapse menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I would like to add two icons to my collapsed bootstrap menu having them equally spaced, including the hamburger menu, and all 3 items centered. As the viewport size changes I want to keep them centered and equally spaced responsively using Bootstraps breakpoints. I have included two examples of what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm just not sure the best way to proceed. I've tried wrapping the logo and icon in the navbar-brand and adjusting it but it did not give me satisfactory results.

[image: Bootstrap navbar example]

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: Make use of the code snippet to replicate the issue or try this: https://www.codeply.com/ and share the link.